# Spring and hibernate database result spring comparison works but still throws an error

Tags: java, spring

I have some values i have stored in mysal table. basically, they are some strings that hold the value up or down.

I want to fetch the data in my table and compare if they are equal to up or down

This is the code

```
String up = "up";
String down = "down";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Query query = currentSession.createSQLQuery(
           "select * from trades where trade_session_status=:trade_session_status AND trade_profit_worker_status=:trade_profit_worker_status");
query.setParameter("trade_session_status", "DONE");
query.setParameter("trade_profit_worker_status", "UNDONE");
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
List < Object[] > result = query.list();

for (Object[] objects: result) {
Integer id = (Integer) objects[0];
String trade_prediction = (String) objects[10];
String trade_result = (String) objects[11];


if(trade_prediction.equals(up) && trade_result.equals(up)) {
}
```

The code works and i can test if the strings are equal but somewhere down the line, i get an error on this line

```
if(trade_prediction.equals(up) && trade_result.equals(up)) {
```

but the program still works.

I get this error

> SEVERE: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.boilerplate.components.Scheduler.profit_cron(Scheduler.java:396)

This is the line 396

> `if(trade_prediction.equals(up) && trade_result.equals(up)) { }`

What could be causing the error?

Comment: objects[10] in your for loop seems to be null due to which trade_prediction will be null causing NPE

Comment: The whole point of using a database is to be able to execute queries to find what you want. Loading the whole table into memory to loop through every row is exactly what you shouldn't do. Not to mention the use of SQL instead of JPQL